# Arrow function, bind and removeListener

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Normally, we can use arrow function to maintain `this` in a class.

```js
class Test {

  constructor() {
    browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((...e) => this.process(...e));
  }

  process() {
    // some code
    this.run();
  }

  run() {
    // some code
  }
}
```

However, that does not work for for `removeListener`, and `bind` can be used.

```js
class Test {

  constructor() {
    this.process = this.process.bind(this);

    if (preference) {
      browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(this.process);
    }
    else {
      browser.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(this.process);
    }
  }

  process() {
    // some code
    this.run();
  }

  run() {
    // some code
  }
}
```

While duplicate event listeners are ignored, the issue with `bind` is that it creates a new function every time. In case of background service worker (or event page), there is a concern that with every restart, a new listener will created.

The class name can also be used instead of `this` to avoid needing `bind`.

Is there better way to handle `this` and `removeListener`?

Comment: It's not a problem because restarting terminates the old environment and old listeners.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you. Out of curiosity, is there a better way?

Comment: Try using separate modules instead of classes in one file.